# Construct a BST from level order (BFS order)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I tried to construct a BST from a given level order (BFS order). I know it's possible but I don't know how can I write this. The problem, is that I had to work with the BFS sequence. So, I can't use recursion here and I had to write my program itratively... And I find that a little confusing.

I tried to do this :

```
public static TreeNode constructBFSTree(ArrayList<Integer> bfs) {
    if (bfs== null) return null;
    ArrayList<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bfs.size()-1; i ++){
             TreeNode node = result.get(i);
             int leftValue = (bfs.get(i+1)!=null)? bfs.get(i+1) : Integer.MAX_VALUE ;
             int rightValue = (bfs.get(i+2)!=null)? bfs.get(i+2) : Integer.MIN_VALUE;

             node.left = (leftValue <= node.data)? new TreeNode(leftValue) : null;
             node.right = (rightValue > node.data)? new TreeNode(rightValue) : null;
             result.add(node);
        }

        return result.get(0);
    }
```

The local ArrayList is not really important here. I just add it to "catch" the first node which is the root of the constructed tree that I should return. The problem is that I only get the root and its child.

How can I write this program?

Comment: A couple of suggestions. 1. Use LinkedList<Integer> instead of array list. That guarantees ordering. 2. try using  the enhanced for loop. for(TreeNode n: result). These would make life easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think it's just a detail no? Because I'm still blocked in this function

Comment: What exactly do you mean by BFS order? There is only in-order, pre-order, post-order, or level-order.

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean the level order. I know that we can construct a unique BST with only the level order but I failed to code it...

Comment: I think you'll need another representation of the order. For example, a 2 node tree either has the child node to the left or right. A level order traversal alone doesn't tell you how that tree is constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you try out the following code? (Note: I haven't tested it as you haven't provided the class definitions. But it should push you in the right direction.)

What I assume about the `TreeNode` class is that its constructor takes an integer and that it initializes the `left` and `right` pointers to `null`. For example:

```
class TreeNode {
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    int key;
    public TreeNode(int key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

The code for the function could then be as follows:

```
public static TreeNode constructBFSTree(ArrayList<Integer> bfs) {
    if (bfs == null || bfs.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Queue<TreeNode> q = new Queue<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(bfs.get(0));
    q.add(root);
    int i = 1;
    while (!q.isEmpty() && i < bfs.size()) {
        TreeNode currentNode = q.poll();
        currentNode.left = new TreeNode(bfs.get(i++));
        q.add(curentNode.left);
        if (i < bfs.length()) {
            currentNode.right = new TreeNode(bfs.get(i++));
            q.add(currentNode.right);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! There some "small" errors (because you didn't test the code I guess). After a litllte correction, it worked for me ! Can you PLEASE take a look in that question also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197476/rewrite-a-c-code-in-java-to-construct-full-binary-tree   please? I'm not good in writing recursion fucntion...

Comment: I;m glad I could help. I will look into it.